# UIWebView corners not rounded

Tags: ios6, uiwebview, calayer

I am using a `UIWebView` for displaying some formatted text. I am using the line:

```
sliderTextWebview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

to round the corners of the `UIWebview`. The corners are not rounded but if you pull the text in the view down or up you can see the rounded corners of the `UIWebView` behind. It appears that the text frame sits above the web view background, but this frame's corners are not rounded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
sliderTextWebview.layer.masksToBounds = YES
```

For Swift 4+, it should be

```
sliderTextWebview.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 3):

These lines will help you out. Try these

```
sliderTextWebview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
sliderTextWebview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set either its layers `maskToBounds` property to `YES` or UIView property `clipsToBounds` to `YES`, to see the rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. This worked for me. Sharing here:

```
webView.clipsToBounds = true
webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```